# ASP.NET MVC 5 folder authorization

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-4

Is there any way I can assign and restrict access to folders for each user, as in `{rootDirectory}/{files}/{userid}`?

For example:

user with id = 12 should have access to "Files/12"

user with id = 13 should have access to "Files/13"

and so on.

I would be grateful to know if this is possible and, if so, how.

Comment: Basically, each user has a specific folder inside your web application, and you want to give access to his/her own folder only. Is that right?

Comment: Yes each user has a specific folder inside my web application, and i want to give access to his/her own folder only. can you please help me on that